# Save conflict while saving SharePoint Online 2013

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online

I have a SPlist and few designer workflows associated with it. Though the edit item and save works for 90% of the time, in some instances, when i try to save the item, Save conflict occurs. I assume this could be becuase of the designer workflows.  Please correct me if I am wrong. Is there a way to eliminate save conflict?

Thanks in Advance!